# Redirecting output to file in Python script

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python(Version 2.6.6) script like Below:

```
import subprocess

id = 834
urllink = "https://xyzm:8443/rest/import-job/" + str(id)
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-k',
    '-u',
    'xxxx:abc',
    '-X',
    'GET',
    urllink
])
```

It returns some JSON output to the terminal. How can I redirect the output to a file, so that I can parse the file and use the same file(data) while executing a POST command?

Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jee

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use bash directly: `curl -ku xxxx:abc -X GET https://xyzm:8443/rest/import-job/834 >yourfile.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting subprocess stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966231/redirecting-subprocess-stdout)

Comment: I need to parse the json file and again upload the file to different userName just like copy. I can use bash script, but there are lots files and involves various logics, so I thought using python script would be a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will write to a file in python 2.6 (I have it set to write what is contained in your output variable), followed by a read of that same file & then the print command will display the output on the terminal.

```
# Write a file
out_file = open("test.txt", "w")
out_file.write(output)
out_file.close()

# Read a file
in_file = open("test.txt", "r")
text = in_file.read()
in_file.close()

print text
```

Comment: Always use a `with` block when dealing with files.

Comment: There is nothing in the output variable since the process returns the output to the terminal. That's why I am looking for the way to capture the output to a file.

Comment: Are you calling this from a terminal, or command prompt?  In which case I would advise calling it like this to write to out.txt:
    `python file.py > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using PyCurl is easy.

Here's an example to get you started:

https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/examples/quickstart/get.py

For some options (setopt) you could get a hint using the --libcurl option of curl.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for taking time to reply.

I achieved the goal by using Python **requests** package without using Linux subprocess module or commands.

Once again, Thank you all!